# HTML select list options lose their CSS font-style when there are too many options

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to style the `options` of a HTML `select` list with a custom font. This works great when there is relatively few options, I'm not sure of the exact amount but I think < 500 or so. However when I exceed this threshold the custom font no longer applies to the options. See this fiddle for an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/eympj0yq/

The options in the left hand fiddle work with the specified font though the ones on the right hand side do not. Has anyone else experienced this and if so are there any workarounds? This is occurring on Chrome 44.0.2403.125 if that makes any difference.

**EDIT:** Just checked on Firefox 39.0 and Internet Explorer 11, and it works in both, so it looks like a Chrome only issue.

**EDIT:** Found a relevant Chromium issue too that says the limit for options is 300 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515014. Opened 5 days ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another issue linked off the issue above https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339 . Basically the Chrome devs decided to disable the option styles after 300+ options because performance reasons.

It is fixed in Canary 46.0.2468.0, so should be in regular Chrome shortly.

This is the revision to fix the problem http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=199776